# Outlet/outside light dead upon plugging in air conditioner

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, light-fixture

1: I immediately upon plugging in air conditioner an outlet on the he opposite wall stopped working

2: The porch light, which happens to be on the same wall as the NOW nonworking outlet also quit working

3: We checked breaker panel first..all was well

4: Reset them ALL anyway...nothing

5: Leads me to believe this could possibly be a wiring issue...which I know nothing about

Comment: Are the AC, porch light, and non-functioning outlet all on the same circuit?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. A tip for future reference: If there wasn't a breaker trip (handle in the middle position, red/orange flag showing in the breaker), there's no need to turn breakers off then back on unless you like resetting all the digital clocks in your house. Good on you for taking the [tour]! While waiting on an answer (or more detail-seeking questions), you can also read through the [help] to get an idea of what's expected and what you can expect around here.

Comment: If you know nothing about wiring you probably should call a professional. Any advice here comes with the assumption that you understand the basics well enough to be safe. At least do some reading of a good house wiring primer.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a load and multiple things quit working without tripping a breaker it is normally a back stab that has failed.

Back stabs are the push in connectors used on many receptacles , the wire is pushed in and a “edge of a metal” contact is made with the wire. Many times when heated the contact point arcs and looses connection.

Some times they start working later after cooling or vibration, but it still needs to be fixed because a heavy load will cause it to fail again.

This type of failure can be traced back to the last working device on the circuit or the first non working device. If you work from the failure working back to the breaker panel it usually only takes pulling  a couple of devices to find a loose wire or even a broken one at a connection or wire but. It can be the hot or the neutral.

If you pull out a device and did not find a problem the stab may have reconnected and the next time the ac is turned on it will open again, so I and other electricians suggest moving back stabbed connections to the screw terminals.

Just make sure to turn the breaker off when doing the work.